# Array of text from a JSON object inserted into <Text> elements via forEach/map not rendering in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm making a Choose Your Own Adventure style game in React Native to learn how everything works. I figured it makes sense to keep the story in a separate JSON file and render it on one screen that updates depending on what arc the user is in.

Problem: when I write a forEach or map or other function to go through the array of paragraphs, the part of the screen it's supposed to be on is blank. Text from other parts of the return area displays fine, but what is supposed to be displayed from the forEach does not. Here's my code:

```
const StoryDisplayScreen = props => {
    const theStory = require('../data/TestStory.json')
    const theArc = 'intro'
    const storyText = () => {
        theStory[theArc].story.forEach((paragraph, i) => {
            <Text style={styles.body}>{paragraph}</Text>
        })
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <ScrollView>
                <View>
                    {storyText()}
                </View>
                <View style={styles.promptNextArcArea}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.promptNextArc}>
                        <Text style={styles.promptNextArcText}>What do you do?</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

In case you're wondering the structure of the JSON file and its contents, I'm using this one to test with: https://github.com/gophercises/cyoa/blob/master/gopher.json

I've tried using map instead, tried putting things in Views, tried putting the forEach/map functions directly into the return section of the code, tried console.log-ing to confirm that my functions are working properly (which they appear to be), and... yeah, I'm at a loss.

Any suggestions?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps [React DevTools](https://blog.logrocket.com/debug-react-applications-with-the-new-react-devtools/) might show the issue?

Comment: Try `return` -  `<ScrollView>
                      <View>
                    theStory[theArc].story.forEach((paragraph, i) => {
          return  <Text style={styles.body}>{paragraph}</Text>
        })
                    </View>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `map` instead of `forEach`.

**Full Working Example: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/story-game)**

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

const StoryDisplayScreen = (props) => {
  const theStory = require('./data/TestStory.json');
  const theArc = 'intro';

  const storyText = () => {
    return theStory[theArc].story.map((paragraph, i) => (
      <Card style={{margin: 5, padding:5}}>
        <Text style={styles.body}>{paragraph}</Text>
      </Card>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <ScrollView>
        <View>{storyText()}</View>
        <View style={styles.promptNextArcArea}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.promptNextArc}>
            <Text style={styles.promptNextArcText}>What do you do?</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default StoryDisplayScreen;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: This does work. I noticed that there are parentheses used for the arrow function instead of curly braces. When I tried it with curly braces, I ran into my error of nothing displaying, but when I use parentheses to enclose the arrow function it works fine. Could you help me understand why please?

Comment: We need to use ```return``` statement when using curly brackets, in case of parentheses we don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, if you want your sort is a function, it must return something, just like the `render` method

```
const sort = () => {
   return (<View></View>)

}
```

you also can make the sort is a view, use it as a variable. like that, both they are can works.

```
const sort = (<View></View>)
```

but the sort must have something return. your way use `for each` and `map` dont return any. there are two ways can do that.

```
const storyText = () => {
        //,first way,define a array, push it in the array
        let  storyViews= []
        theStory[theArc].story.forEach((paragraph, i) => {
            sortyviews.push(<Text style={styles.body}>{paragraph}</Text>)
        })
        return soortView;
    }
```

the second way is to return directly a array

```
const storyText = () => {
        //,first way,define a array, push it in the array
        let  storyViews= []
        storyViews = theStory[theArc].story.map((paragraph, i) => {
            return (<Text style={styles.body}>{paragraph}</Text>)
        })
        return soortView;
        
    }
```

for more about the array operate to see the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)